# Why can’t we justify offering animal sacrifice using Bhagwad Gita?

Tags: shaktism

I see offering animal sacrifices to god as a way we humans can put to applications the principles of Chapter 2 .i.e. sankhya yoga in Bhagwad Geeta.

1.Verse 28 says not to lament over the loss of bodies - When we offer animal sacrifice, we offer a sacrifice of the emotional attachment which we form with the animal that we have reared with love and affection
2. I agree that animal sacrifice will cause pain to the animal but again in verse 15 chapter 2 Krishna says treat pleasure and pain alike.

3. And finally in chapter 19 krishna says soul cannot be killed, so even when I am offering the animal sacrifice, I am simply sacrificing one of my materialistic possession and I am not essentially killing any soul via the process.

So wont all these arguments make animal sacrifice justified as per Bhagwad geeta?

Comment: Deleted my comment earlier, I try again : I think we’re all going to have different opinions on things. People will have very different ideas on so much of this. My personal opinion is that animal sacrifice is not ok, is not a good thing, and may be derived from rather spurious/specious misunderstood religious texts. So I’m against trying to justify/legitimize it.